# Angular 7 - version control Git in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, git, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular7

I'm new to **Angular** (also to **Git** and **VS Code**).
When I change something in my Angular project, I always get notifications that I should commit updates in my project. But I haven't logged anywhere to my **GitHub** account, so I'm interested what are all those commits about? Here's screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about your local git repository, which is present when you have a `.git` hidden folder on your project.

The files present on the screenshot, below **"Changes"** are the one you can see with the command `git status`

Using the **"Commit all"**, is equivalent to execute the 2 following commands, which respectively *add all current changes to the next commit*, and *commit previously staged changes*

```
git add .
git commit
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use git in locally. Git is a distributed version control system in contrast of svn (svn is a centralized verison control system).

Check diffs here: https://backlog.com/blog/git-vs-svn-version-control-system/

If you have repository in for eg.: github or bitbucket:

- You can commit your changes (but this is only in your local machine) after commit you have to push these changes to be available on your repository.

In your case you can not push only commit, create branches, rebase your code etc. But only in local.

Answer (score 1):

Locally, until you will insert a Git-services account.